# rails callback before 'new' of a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-models

I have a model `base_table`, and I have a `extended_table` which has extra properties to further extend my `base_table`. (I would have different extended_tables, to add different properties to my base_table, but that's non-related to the question I'm asking here).

The model definition for my `base_table` is like:

```
class BaseTable < ActiveRecord::Base
  module BaseTableInclude
    def self.included(base)
      base.belongs_to :base_table, autosave:true, dependent: :destroy
      # do something more when this module is included
    end
  end
end
```

And the model definition for my `extended_table` is like:

```
class TennisQuestionaire < ActiveRecord::Base
  include BaseTable::BaseTableInclude
end
```

Now I what I want is the code below:

```
params = {base_table: {name:"Songyy",age:19},tennis_ball_num:3}
t = TennisQuestionaire.new(params)
```

When I created my `t`, I want the base_table to be instantiated as well.

One fix I can come up with, is to parse the params to create the base_table object, before TennisQuestionaire.new was called upon the params. It's something like having a "before_new" filter here. But I cannot find such kind of filter when I was reading the documentation.

Additionally, I think another way is to override the 'new' method. But this is not so clean.

NOTE: There's one method called `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, seems to do what I want, but it doesn't work upon a `belongs_to` relation.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Seems like you should reverse the relationship and use a `has_one` instead.

Answer (score 0):

After some trails&error, the solution is something like this:

```
class BaseTable < ActiveRecord::Base
  module BaseTableInclude
    def initialize(*args,&block)
      handle_res = handle_param_args(args) { |params| params[:base_table] = BaseTable.new(params[:base_table]) }
      super(*args,&block)
    end

    private
    def handle_param_args(args)
      return unless block_given?

      if args.length > 0
        params = args[0]
        if (params.is_a? Hash) and params[:base_table].is_a? Hash
          yield params
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```